# How can I check if a user-entered string matches a specific format?

Tags: java, regex, validation

I'm writing a program to check if a string the user enters is a valid phone number. The only qualification for a valid number is matches the format "ddd-ddd-dddd" where each d is a digit. How do I check if the string matches this format?

Comment: You should look at regular expressions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: The `String` class even has a method named `matches` - should be hard to miss when you search for "string matches".

Comment: provide your code. So, I could assist you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use regular expression. Below is few lines of code that will be useful.

```
  String sPhoneNumber1 = "605-888-9999";
  String sPhoneNumber2 = "605-888-9991";
  //String sPhoneNumber3 = "605-8838-9993";

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sPhoneNumber);

  if (matcher.matches()) {
      System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
  }
  else
  {
      System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form XXX-XXXXXXX");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String whatUserEntered = "1223-123-1234";
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d", whatUserEntered));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "123-345-6789";
if(!s.matches("^\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$"))
{
    System.out.println("This is not a valid phone number");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("This is a valid phone number");
}
```

And here a good site to learn regex:
http://regexone.com/

Comment: @user3493397 Feel free to mark my answer as the correct one. ^^

Answer (score 0):

You would use a regular expression to match it. The easiest regular expression to match it is:

```
/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}/
```

You can also use:

```
/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/
```

**Javascript:**

```
var test = '111-222-3333';
var regex = /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/g;
console.log(test.match(regex));
```

**Expected output:**

```
["111-222-3333"]
```

Wiki has a good source for learning regular expressions:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

There are also heaps of online resources.

Edit: Missed the Java requirement
From the Java 7 docs:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Applying that to above:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("111-222-3333");
boolean b = m.matches();

if (b) {
System.out.println("Matches!");
} else {
System.out.println("Doesn't match!");
}
```

Remember to escape () your backslashes when using string literals in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not great with java but if i remember right,

To validate a string in java looks like this:

```
if(cellnum.matches(\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4})
{//this is valid}
```